# Website bug when scrolling past interactive map

Tags: macos, safari

Could you help me confirm an issue that I’m experiencing in Safari on macOS?

###### Steps to reproduce:

1. Open this web page: https://blogs.worldbank.org/opendata/new-world-bank-country-classifications-income-level-2022-2023
2. Position the mouse cursor in the center of the screen near the title of the page
3. Start scrolling the page up and down past the interactive map that is located at the beginning of the article

###### What happened:

When the page scrolled down, and the mouse cursor appeared on top of the world map, scrolling was interrupted, and the map was zoomed in.

###### What should have happened:

Scrolling should not be interrupted by the map.

###### Additional notes:

I have recorded a video that shows this issue in my Safari browser. I’ve posted this video on Twitter:

https://twitter.com/simevidas/status/1543275935323099137

Please check if you’re also experiencing this issue. I would like to rule out the possibility that it’s just me.

Comment: The behaviour is decided by the web site, not Safari. They have some sort of 'mouseover' action which changes behaviour.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you also experiencing this issue in Safari? Could you check?

Comment: Yes, of course, because this isn't a bug it's a feature. Many websites show comparable behaviour, whatever the browser. If it annoys you, learn to get the mouse out of the way of page content whilst scrolling. There's one site I go to has active highlighting over every sub-section you hover over [which is hundreds per page]. You eventually learn to just not leave the mouse over the page, hang over the scroll bars instead.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Safari on the Mac, and what you are seeing is true of almost any page with an interactive map that I have ever encountered.

Once the pointer is over the map, scrolling down is by design interpreted as "zoom out".

In short, this isn't a bug: it is designed behaviour.

Comment: I understand, but I need to get a confirmation from other people that they’re also experiencing this specific issue. If it’s not a problem, could you go through the steps?

Comment: @Tetsujin second comment makes clear that this is something which will happen to everyone. Besides that probably at least everyone commenting here checked out the page the OP linked to see wether they can contribute anything (additionally).

Answer (score 1):

As @Alan stated, this is the designed behaviour.

You can eliminate all pointer interaction with the iframe by adding `pointer-events: none`. This would stop the map from interfering with the scrolling of the page but would also eliminate all user interaction with the map, making it the same as a static image.

I believe that there may be a solution found in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736169/disable-map-scrolling-open-street-maps) question.

Regardless this is the intended and expected behaviour and users will understand how to deal with it.

Comment: Are you also experiencing this issue in Safari? Could you check?

Comment: Yes, what you describe is what I experienced in Safari.

Comment: This is no different than scrolling a page with a scrollable text box. Once the pointer is over the text box, it will scroll the content of the text box, not the page.

Comment: All a user must do is move their pointer to the side of the element in question, and the page will continue to scroll.